# Can I use reserved word as parameter of a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, reserved-words

```
var myName = 'John';
function greet(name) {
  console.log('Hello, ' + name);
}
greet(myName);
```

Here I'm using 'name' as a parameter of the greet(). Since we know that we can't use javascript reserved word as a variable name, could we use them as the param? Or are they restricted for anywhere in the script to be used as an identifier?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `name` isn't a reserved word.

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: Yes, you can, because name is not a reserved word.

Comment: The restrictions on [*parameters*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-FunctionDeclaration) are identical to those on [*variable names*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement) (see [*BindingIdentifier*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-BindingIdentifier)), they both must be valid identifiers and not reserved words.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Here on this list it's being said to avoid identifiers as names of JavaScript variables. [http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) and in the w3schools reference page it's recommended like 'You should also avoid using the name of JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods' [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

What is the explicit recommendation?

Comment: @nirjhor—forget sites like w3schools, MDN, etc. Reserved words are clearly articulated in the one place that matters: [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words), though for the life of me I can't work out why they aren't listed alphabetically.

Comment: Indeed you should not use the names that JS defines. Note the "should not", not "can not". It is perfectly legal to do `parseInt = () => 17`, but it's probably not the best of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_2015) for any purpose other than how they are intended in the grammar of JavaScript. That is, they cannot be used as identifiers anywhere, even as property names in object literals, they must be escaped with quotes.

Here is a list of reserved keywords as of ECMAScript 2015:

- [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)
- [`case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)
- [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)
- [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class)
- [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
- [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)
- [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)
- [`default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/default)
- [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
- [`do`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)
- [`else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class)
- [`finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)
- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)
- [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
- [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)
- [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)
- [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)
- [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)
- [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)
- [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)
- [`try`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
- [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)
- [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)
- [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)
- [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)

Comment: That list does not include future [*reserved words*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-future-reserved-words) or those that are reserved in strict mode.

Comment: @RobG Yes, but the link does. If they care enough to use strict mode (which I doubt, given the question) or to future-proof their program, then they can use the link to see the rest.

Comment: I guess my point is that links to the relevant parts of ECMA-262 with regard to [*reserved words*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words) and [*identifier name*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-IdentifierName) covers everything with normative references. Text can then be added to explain content at the links if required. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please check here for a list of JavaScript reserved words: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords

You cannot use reserved words for  variables, functions, methods, or object identifiers. Function parameters will be treated as variables inside its function, hence it cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you for correcting, I have edited that. I saw w3schools on the top when searching for it, so I just took that from there.

Comment: Your updated link is for ECMAScript 5 standard, and is not comprehensive for all of ECMAScript 2015

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I have a question, if I use reserved words in ES2015 and not using transpiler, would they be neglected at this stage?

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided will work. - `name` is not a reserved word.

However, to answer your question:  No - if you were to try to use a reserved word such as `const` or `var` you would get an error.