# Can I declare variable named "default" in a Typescript namespace?

Tags: typescript, namespaces

There is an existing API which I create its typing file.

The API has an `enum` like variable with property `default`.

```js
var SortBy = {
  default: 'default',
  //... rest of the options
}
```

My problem is, when I'm trying to declare a variable with the name `default` I get an error:

> Variable declaration expected.

My code is:

```js
namespace SortBy {
  const default: 'default';
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20SortBy%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20default%3A%20%27default%27%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Although I know that I can't use `default` as a variable name, I'm looking for a way to create type declaration to the API snippet above

Comment: `default` is a reserved word and is not a valid identifier in JavaScript or TypeScript.  You *can* use it as a property name, as in the `var SortBy =` line.

Comment: I believe that `default` is a reserved keyword. This seems to work `namespace SortBy {
  const Default = 'default';
}`

Comment: It seems that it's working with javascript: http://jsbin.com/refenecifo/edit?js maybe there is a different way (not with namespace necessarily) to declare the type so I could access to `SortBy.default`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use reserved word as parameter of a function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426734/can-i-use-reserved-word-as-parameter-of-a-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @yivi thanks but not really. I was looking for a typescript definition, not plain javascript.